# Custom Info Box at end of posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-field, shortcode, bloginfo

I'm pretty new to WordPress so there are some parts of it I have difficulty working with. I run a small scale gaming niche website which focuses on just a small group of video games, and what I'm trying to do is have a short "game info box" at the end of each post. Basically, think of an author info box that instead of having info on the author, it has info on the game the news post is discussing. I want it to look like a box with a short text description of the game, the game name linking to a specific page (I'll be making a custom page per game), and a small icon/image of the game. A good example is what can be found at the end of posts in this WordPress website: http://www.koi-nya.net/2015/02/05/persona-5-presenta-su-primer-trailer-con-gameplay/
See how there's a Persona 5 game info box at the end of their post.

I've seen the Shortcodes Ultimate plugin and that seems to do the trick given that they have custom boxes, but I have a problem with that. Said plugin requires you to rewrite the entire info box again and again whenever you post - my site, on the other hand, has thousands of news posts that may focus on few games - making reposting a big hassle.

Hence, what I'm looking for is a plugin that may allow having a separate database for the info of the game, and then having an option or shortcode to include the info box everytime I post a new post. That way we won't have to retype it every single time. Is there such a plugin that can achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off topic however you can use code for this. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`register a new widget`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes#How_to_Register_a_Widget_Area) in your functions file. Best to [`create a child theme`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for code additions and modifications.

1. You can [`call the new sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes#How_to_display_new_Widget_Areas) in your single.php or content.php file (recommended for themes without custom hooks)

Or

2. Use a [`custom function`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes#Create_New_Widget_Area_Using_Custom_Function) with the [`is_singular('post')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) conditional tag in your functions file and return the sidebar after the content using the_content filter

Comment: Will registering it as a widget allow me to manually pick what I include whenever I post?

Comment: It creates a new widget area which you can populate with any widget.

Comment: Ohh, that explains it! Would it also work in a sense that, whenever I make a new post, it will also allow me to pick what to include in that widget?